# How to configure docker-compose.yml to up a container as root

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to connect two containers with a docker-compose-yml, but it isn't working. This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
    datapower:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "9090:9090"
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        image: "microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest"
        environment:
            SA_PASSWORD: "your_password"
            ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
        ports:
        - "1433:1433"
```

When I make:

> docker-compose up

This up my two containers. Then I stop one container and then I run the same container stoped independiently like:

> docker-compose run -u root --name nameofcontainer 'name of container named in docker-compose.yml'

With this, the connection of the containers works. Exists a method to configure my docker-compose.yml to connect my containers like root without stop a container and run independently?

Comment: docker containers are already run by superuser, so why do you need to run them as root? wouldnt be easier to do `su` to switch to root and then start the containers?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

**Update:**

There exists the `user` property that can be set in the compose file. This is documented in [docker-compose file reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir).

```yaml
...
services:
    datapower:
        build: .
        user: root
        ports:
            - "9090:9090"
        depends_on:
            - db
...
```

Comment: how do you specify the user in the `docker-compose up` command?

Comment: There is no option to do that https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/. It also doesn't make sense to pass it from command line since the user is per container. The only way is to set it inside the compose file.

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler you can hack it if you want to pass from command `USER=root docker-compose up` and on compose file: `user: $USER`

Comment: To add to @Theo response - this does give you the ability to run _commands_ to generate what the user would be, like `USER=$(id -u) docker-compose up` and in the compose file `user: $USER`.  This is useful when you want to run the container as a non-root user (as you should _always strongly consider doing_), and you need to programmatically figure out said user.

Comment: Does it work within stack files too, to [deploy a stack to a swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/stack-deploy/) ?

Comment: How do you specify password for the user?

Comment: Same question as @VinShahrdar

Comment: Just in case people don't know, you can always use plain docker (not docker-compose) to connect to a container you lifted up with docker-compose by using: docker exec -it -u root:root container_name /bin/bash

Answer (score 19):

## Setting both a User *AND* a Group in `docker-compose.yml`:

Discovered another way to set not only the ***user*** but also the ***group*** in a docker-compose.yml file which is NOT documented in the Docker Compose File Reference @yamenk helpfully provides in the accepted answer.

I needed to raise a container expressly setting both a user **AND** a group and found that the `user:` parameter in `docker-compose.yml` can be populated as a **UID:GID** mapping delimited by a colon.

Below is a snippet from my docker-compose.yml file where this form was tested and found to work correctly:

```
services:
 zabbix-agent:
  image: zabbix/zabbix-agent2:ubuntu-6.0-latest
  container_name: DockerHost1-zabbix-agent2
  user: 0:0
<SNIP>
```

Reference:

https://github.com/zabbix/zabbix-docker/issues/710

Hope this saves others wasted cycles looking for this!

Comment: It is documented: `domainname, hostname, ipc, mac_address, privileged, read_only, shm_size, stdin_open, tty, user, working_dir
Each of these is a single value, analogous to its docker run counterpart. Note that mac_address is a legacy option.`  https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir