# Run a command as root with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

While in the process of painstakingly sculpting a Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml, what is **THE RIGHT WAY** to run root shell in work-in-progress containers (without actually starting their services!) in order to debug issues? I need to be able to run the shell as root, because only root has full access to files containing the information that I need to examine.

I **can** modify Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml in order to achieve this goal; as I wrote above, I am in the process of sculpting those anyway.

The problem however is that about the only way I can think of is putting `USER root` in Dockerfile or `user: root` in docker-compose.yml, but those SimplyHaveNoEffect™ in the `docker-compose run <service> bash` scenario. `whoami` in the shell thus started says `neo4j` instead of `root`, no matter what I try.

I **might** add `sudo` to the image, which doesn't have `sudo`, but this should be considered **last resort**. Also using docker directly instead of docker-compose is less than preferable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All of the commands that launch shells in containers (including, for example, [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) have a `--user` option and so you can specify an arbitrary user for your debugging shell.

```sh
docker-compose run -u root <service> bash
```

If you're in the process of debugging your image build, note that each build step produces an image, and you can run a debugging shell on that image.  (For example, examine the step before a `RUN` step to see what the filesystem looks like before it executes, or after to see its results.)

```
$ docker build .
...
Step 7/9 : RUN ...
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 55c91a5dca05
...
$ docker run --rm -it -u root 55c91a5dca05 bash
```

In both of these cases the command (`bash`) overrides the `CMD` in the Dockerfile.  If you have an `ENTRYPOINT` wrapper script that will still run, but the standard `exec "$@"` command will launch your debugging shell.  If you've put your default command to run as `ENTRYPOINT`, change it to `CMD` to better support this use case (and also the wrapper entrypoint pattern, should you need it).

If you really can't change the Dockerfile, you can override the `ENTRYPOINT` too, but it's a little awkward.

```sh
docker run --rm -it -u root --entrypoint ls myimage -al /app
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use it this way:

```
version: '3'
services:
  jenkins:
    user: root
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    ports: 
      - "8080:8080"
      - "50000:50000"
    volumes:
      - /jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
```

you can refer to [How to configure docker-compose.yml to up a container as root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48727548/how-to-configure-docker-compose-yml-to-up-a-container-as-root/48730146)