# Containerizing Cordapp with Docker Image and Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, corda

When running Corda in docker with external Postgres DB configurations, I get insufficient privileges to access error.

**Note:**
Corda: 4.6 Postgresql: 9.6
Docker engine 20.10.6
Docker-compose: docker-compose version 1.29.1, build c34c88b2

**docker-compose.yml file:**

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  partyadb:
    hostname: partyadb
    container_name: partyadb
    image: "postgres:9.6"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: partyadb
    ports:
    - 5432
  partya:
    hostname: partya
#    image: corda/corda-zulu-java1.8-4.7:RELEASE
    image: corda/corda-zulu-java1.8-4.6:latest
    container_name: partya
    ports:
    - 10006
    - 2223
    command: /bin/bash -c "java -jar /opt/corda/bin/corda.jar run-migration-scripts -f /etc/corda/node.conf --core-schemas --app-schemas && /opt/corda/bin/run-corda"
    volumes:
    - ./partya/node.conf:/etc/corda/node.conf:ro
    - ./partya/certificates:/opt/corda/certificates:ro
    - ./partya/persistence.mv.db:/opt/corda/persistence/persistence.mv.db:rw
    - ./partya/persistence.trace.db:/opt/corda/persistence/persistence.trace.db:rw
#    - ./partya/logs:/opt/corda/logs:rw
    - ./shared/additional-node-infos:/opt/corda/additional-node-infos:rw
    - ./shared/cordapps:/opt/corda/cordapps:rw
    - ./shared/drivers:/opt/corda/drivers:ro
    - ./shared/network-parameters:/opt/corda/network-parameters:rw
    environment:
    - ACCEPT_LICENSE=${ACCEPT_LICENSE}
    depends_on:
      - partyadb
```

**Error:**

```
[ERROR] 12:41:24+0000 [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging. - Exception during node startup. Corda started with insufficient privileges to access /opt/corda/additional-node-infos/nodeInfo-5B........................................47D
```

Answer (score 2):

The `corda/corda-zulu-java1.8-4.6:latest` [image runs under the user `corda`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/corda/corda-zulu-java1.8-4.6-rc04/latest/images/sha256-fa0d5b43126124b56bf3640984f8e5ef48e7c0bf8469ccf4409e7a6d996d8571?context=explore), not root.  This user has user id 1000, and also is in a group called `corda`, also with gid 1000:

```
corda@5bb6f196a682:~$ id -u corda
1000
corda@5bb6f196a682:~$ groups corda
corda : corda
corda@5bb6f196a682:~$ id -G corda
1000
```

The problem here seems to be that the file you are mounting into the docker container (`./shared/additional-node-infos/nodeInfo-5B`) does not have permissions setup in such a way as to allow this user to access it.  I'm assuming the user needs read and write access.  A *very simple* fix would be to give `other` read and write access to this file:

```
$ chmod o+rw ./shared/additional-node-infos/nodeInfo-5B
```

There are plenty of other ways to manage this kind of permissions issue in docker, but remember that the permissions are based on uid/gid which usually do not map nicely from your host machine into the docker container.

Answer (score 1):

So the error itself describes that it's a permission problem.

I don't know if you crafted this dockerfile yourself, you may want to take a look at generating them with the dockerform task (https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.8/generating-a-node.html#use-cordform-and-dockerform-to-create-a-set-of-local-nodes-automatically)

This permission problem could be that you're setting only read / write within the container:

```
 - ./shared/additional-node-infos:/opt/corda/additional-node-infos:rw
```

or it could be that you need to change the permissions on the shared folder. Try changing the permissions of `shared` to `777` and see if that works, then restrict your way back down to permissions you're comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

I just configure the image to be run as root. This works but may not be safe. Simply add

```yaml
services:
    cordaNode:
        user: root
```

to the service configuration.

Ref: [How to configure docker-compose.yml to up a container as root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48727548/how-to-configure-docker-compose-yml-to-up-a-container-as-root)

Comment: [Link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) are considered very low quality and [can get deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), please put the important parts from the linked resource into the answer body.