# DockerOperator failure: Permission denied for docker.sock

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

I run Airflow using Docker-compose and I wanted to create a DAG with a DockerOperator in order to run a docker container.

The thing is I keep on getting the same error when looking at the logs for the DAG in Airflow:

```
[2021-05-12 11:37:38,060] {taskinstance.py:1482} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1287, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1333, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1282, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1042, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 980, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

The file at issue is docker.stock which has the following rights:

```
srw-rw----. 1 root docker
```

Note that in the Docker-compose yml file I specified the user to be the default one and the group to be root, plus I mounted the docker.sock directory as follows:

```
- /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:z
```

And here is the docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.0.2}
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW_UID: 8854
    AIRFLOW_GID: 0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_FOLDER: '/data/python/airflow/dags'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
  volumes:
    - /data/graylog/python/airflow/dags:/data/python/airflow/dags:z
    - /data/graylog/python/airflow/logs:/data/python/airflow/logs:z
    - /data/graylog/python/airflow/plugins:/data/python/airflow/plugins:z
    - /data/graylog/python/timestamp:/data/python/timestamp:z
    - /data/graylog/python/python_scripts:/data/python/python_scripts:z
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:z
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-8854}:${AIRFLOW_GID:-0}"
  depends_on:
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    restart: always

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    restart: always

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: version
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}

  flower:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery flower
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

Can someone help me with this please? Thanks

Comment: please post your docker compose file.

Comment: I've just added it

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? So far, the only solutions I have found are to add docker.sock rw privileges to all users or to add the user running the container to docker group and group 0. To my surprise, even adding privileged: true to celery-worker container does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue you can use :

```sh
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

After that you will have a permission to your docker .
I hope that can help you to resolve your issue .

Comment: Thanks rassakra for your swift answer

Do you think there would be a way to solve the issue without using sudo chmod and rather by adding docker group in my Docker-compose yml file for example?

Comment: Doing this would allow every user on the host the ability to run commands as root, without any password verification or other checks.

Comment: try with cmod   without change anything in your  docker-compse . or add your user to docker group also resolve the issue

Comment: My default user, which is the user in Docker host, is in the docker group in the original host. However, in the Docker host, the only group my user is part of is root. How could I make my default user in Docker host be part of the docker group? 

Note that I already tried to use group_add: <docker group id> in my docker-compose yml file without success

Comment: sudo groupadd docker  after that sudo usermod -aG docker $USER , service docker restart

Comment: Ok thanks.
Is it possible to put those commands in the docker-compose yaml file?

Comment: In the docker compose you can only add a user like these : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48727548/how-to-configure-docker-compose-yml-to-up-a-container-as-root/48730146

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by removing `USER XXX` from my Dockerfile.