# Permission denied when trying to run DockerOperator on Airflow

Tags: macos, docker, airflow

I am running Airflow 1.10.12 via Docker Desktop 2.0.0.3 on a Mac OS X Catalina. In my DAG I have something like:

```
DockerOperator(
    api_version='1.21',
    docker_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock',
    command='/bin/sleep 30',
    image='centos:latest',
    network_mode='bridge',
    task_id='docker_op_tester',
    dag=dag,
)
```

and in my docker-compose file:

```
scheduler:
    image: apache/airflow:1.10.12-python3.8
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ....etc
```

When I run the the DAG it fails in the `DockerOperator` with:

```
    [2021-05-28 15:12:47,157] {taskinstance.py:1150} ERROR - ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1255, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 950, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I looked around and tried a few things included some brutal `chmod 777...` but nothing seems to work. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The `official` image runs by default with 50000 user and this user is not in `docker` group that is required to be able to run docker commands.

You have a few options (but some of them are only available in 2.0.2+ version of airflow:

1. Create a user in your Host machine with uid = 50000 and add it to the `docker` group. This is a bit of a hack though
2. Run the image as `root` user (but this one will only run with 2.0.2+ image of Airflow I think.
   Example here: [How to configure docker-compose.yml to up a container as root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48727548/how-to-configure-docker-compose-yml-to-up-a-container-as-root/48730146)
3. Run the image as your "host" user (if your "host" user is already added to docker group) - this might involve passing parameters to docker-compose commands, or creating an .env file as described in https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#initializing-environment

Comment: hi @Jarek,  thanks for these suggestions. I am using the newest version of airflow (2.1.0) and i tried the 3rd option but I am still running into this Permission denied error. i set the `AIRFLOW_UID=$(id -u)` which is the host uid as instructed.

Comment: Hard to say what is wrong. But you should try to simply enter the docker image manually - something like   `docker run --user UID:0 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -it <image name> bash` with the user and manually mounting the docker socket - to see what wie